# How to serialize a regular expression type using .NET XML serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex

How can I serialize a string from XML into a class property of type `Regex`?

Here's the elements in the XML file:

```
  <IncludeRegex><![CDATA[#include\\s*\\\"\\s*(?<FileName>.+\\\\*\\.*.+)\\s*\\\"]]></IncludeRegex>
  <IncludeDefineRegex><![CDATA[#define\s*[A-Za-z_0-9]+\s*\""\s*(?<FileName>.+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*\""]]></IncludeDefineRegex>
```

In my class, that I serialize, I have these properties:

```
public Regex IncludeRegex { get; set; }
public Regex IncludeDefineRegex { get; set; }
```

The rest of the class serializes without a problem, but the `Regex` properties fail to serialize.  One option is to have alternate properties:

```
public string IncludeRegex { get; set; }
public string IncludeDefineRegex { get; set; }
[XmlIgnore]
public Regex IncludeRegexActual { get; private set; }

[XmlIgnore]
public Regex IncludeDefineRegexActual { get; private set; }
```

And set these properties in the setters of IncludeRegex and IncludeDefineRegex or an init function.  This works, but can I do it without the duplicate properties?

Comment: What part of the Regex do you want to serialize, other than the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with regular XML serialization, you have to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to control the serialization directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that Regex cannot be serialized. That can be solved by implementing `IXmlSerializable`. As you cannot change the `Regex` class, you have to handle it in another class. You might be able to do something like this (untested, out of my head):

```
public class MyRegEx : Regex, IXmlSerializable {...}
```

Now you have to implement the interface and have to use that class instead of Regex.

Comment: I believe you mean `IXmlSerializable`